# How to use hover and position:absolute properly?

Tags: html, css

I am not very experienced but I wanted to make a hoverable dropdown
My problems:

1. hover doesn't work
2. absolute position is wierd i wanted it under txt 5
   I last made a navbar like this a few years ago maybe i have forgotten or maybe i have written complete bs. Anyways thankyou to whoever answers this.

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;}
body{
    background-color: #000;
}
p.heading{
    font-family: helvetica;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #ccffff;
    padding: 10px;
    color:#000080;
}
.nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ff4d4d;
    float: left;
}
ul li{
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
button.btn{
    border: none;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ff4d4d;
    color:azure;
}
button.btn:hover{
    border: none;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#ccffff;
    color: #000;
}
button.drp{
    border: none;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ff4d4d;
    color:azure;
}
button.drp:hover{
    border: none;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#ccffff;
    color: #000;
}



button.d{
    border: none;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #ff4d4d;
    color:azure;
}
button.d:hover{
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color:#ccffff;
    color: #000;
}

.li{
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 130px;
    color:azure;
}
button.drp :hover  .li{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "stylesheet.css">
    </head>
        <body>
            <div class = heading>
                <p class = heading>Heading</p>
            </div>
            <div class = nav>
                <ul class = nav>
                 <li><button class = btn> Txt1 </button></li>
                 <li><button class = btn> Txt2 </button></li>
                 <li><button class = btn> Txt3 </button></li>
                 <li><button class = btn> Txt4 </button></li>
                 <li><button class = drp> Txt5 </button></li>
                 <li class = li><ul>
                        <li><button class = d>txt6</button></li>
                        <li><button class = d>txt7</button></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
                </ul>     
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

a simple suggestion would also work i just feel like the easiest thing is flying right over

Answer (score 1):

You can simply trigger the dropdown using the **li** itself not the **button**  in the first snippet I just added a *class* to the **li** that opens the dropdown when it hovers and when the hidden **li** itself is hovered to stay dropped down.

```
 .dropmysibling:hover + .li ul,.li:hover ul{
   display: block;
 }
```

this is the sibling method, but it's a bad implementation because it's nearly impossible to position an element based on its sibling.

a better way to do this is by using the child method by putting the hidden menu inside the **li** that opens it, and that makes it easy to position.
Check the other snippet.

Here is the **bad** method - (**sibling method**):

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;}
body{
    background-color: #000;
}
p.heading{
    font-family: helvetica;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #ccffff;
    padding: 10px;
    color:#000080;
}
.nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ff4d4d;
    float: left;
    display:flex;
    align-items:stretch;
}
ul li{
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
button.btn{
    border: none;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ff4d4d;
    color:azure;
}
button.btn:hover{
    border: none;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#ccffff;
    color: #000;
}
button.drp{
    border: none;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ff4d4d;
    color:azure;
}
button.drp:hover{
    border: none;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#ccffff;
    color: #000;
}



button.d{
    border: none;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #ff4d4d;
    color:azure;
}
button.d:hover{
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color:#ccffff;
    color: #000;
}
.li{
  position:relative;
}
.li ul{
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 130px;
    color:azure;
    top:100%;
    left:-75px;
}
 .dropmysibling:hover + .li ul,.li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "stylesheet.css">
    </head>
        <body>
            <div class = heading>
                <p class = heading>Heading</p>
            </div>
            <div class = nav>
                <ul class = nav>
                 <li><button class = btn> Txt1 </button></li>
                 <li><button class = btn> Txt2 </button></li>
                 <li><button class = btn> Txt3 </button></li>
                 <li><button class = btn> Txt4 </button></li>
                 <li class="dropmysibling"><button class = drp> Txt5 </button></li>
                 <li class = li><ul>
                        <li><button class = d>txt6</button></li>
                        <li><button class = d>txt7</button></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
                </ul>     
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Here is a **better** method - (**child method**):

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;}
body{
    background-color: #000;
}
p.heading{
    font-family: helvetica;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #ccffff;
    padding: 10px;
    color:#000080;
}
.nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ff4d4d;
    float: left;
    display:flex;
    align-items:stretch;
}
ul li{
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
button.btn{
    border: none;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ff4d4d;
    color:azure;
}
button.btn:hover{
    border: none;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#ccffff;
    color: #000;
}
button.drp{
    border: none;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ff4d4d;
    color:azure;
}
button.drp:hover{
    border: none;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#ccffff;
    color: #000;
}



button.d{
    border: none;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #ff4d4d;
    color:azure;
}
button.d:hover{
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color:#ccffff;
    color: #000;
}
.dropdownmychild{
  postistion:relative;
}
.dropdownmychild > ul{
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 130px;
    color:azure;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
}
.dropdownmychild:hover >ul{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "stylesheet.css">
    </head>
        <body>
            <div class = heading>
                <p class = heading>Heading</p>
            </div>
            <div class = nav>
                <ul class = nav>
                 <li><button class = btn> Txt1 </button></li>
                 <li><button class = btn> Txt2 </button></li>
                 <li><button class = btn> Txt3 </button></li>
                 <li><button class = btn> Txt4 </button></li>
                 <li class="dropdownmychild"><button class = drp> Txt5 </button>
                 <ul>
                        <li><button class = d>txt6</button></li>
                        <li><button class = d>txt7</button></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
                </ul>     
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

I also gave the .nav a **display: flex;** and **align-items: stretch;**

Answer (score 0):

I also change your HTML structure and give them some class names. You can compare it with your code. You should also improve yourself about elements (tags), class name, and ID on HTML and CSS. You will take errors even you write the correct code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <title>Document</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="heading">
          <h1 class="heading__title">Heading</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
          <ul class="nav__list">
            <li class="nav__item">
              <a href="#" class="nav__link">Item 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav__item">
              <a href="#" class="nav__link">Item 2</a>
              <ul class="drop-list">
                <li class="drop-list__item">
                  <a href="#" class="drop-list__link">Drop Item 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="drop-list__item">
                  <a href="#" class="drop-list__link">Drop Item 2</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Item 3</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Item 4</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Item 5</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Item 6</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Item 7</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

```
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color: #000;
    }
    
    .heading__title {
      font-family: helvetica;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: bold;
      background-color: #ccffff;
      padding: 10px;
      color: #000080;
    }
    
    .nav {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #ff4d4d;
      float: left;
    }
    
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    
    a:link,
    a:visited {
      color: azure;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .nav__list {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .nav__item {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 10px 20px;
    }
    
    .nav__item:hover .drop-list {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .nav__link {
      border: none;
      font-family: helvetica;
      font-size: 16px;
      background-color: #ff4d4d;
    
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .drop-list {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      top: 40px;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #ff4d4d;
      color: azure;
      display: none;
    }
    
    .drop-list__item {
      padding: 5px;
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have changed out the HTML format a bit, the buttons are removed and class names are added, CSS flex-box is used as it's better than the float being used.

Now for the HTML, I would say that is better to add class/id names that are relatively to understand at a glance

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: helvetica,sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
.heading{
    text-align: center;

    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 700;
    
    padding: 10px;

    background-color: #ccffff;
    color:#000080;
}
.menu_ul{
    /* float is rarely used flex anf grids are what is used */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    
    background-color: #ff4d4d;
}
.menu_list_items{
    padding: 10px;
}
.menu_list_items a{
    font-size: 1em;

    color:azure;
}
.drpDown{
    display: none;
}
.menu_list_items:hover .drpDown{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- add a link tag to import google fonts into the html file for the font support "helvetica" -->
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <header>
            <h1 class="heading">Heading</h1>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <ul class="menu_ul">
                <li class="menu_list_items"><a href="#">Txt1</a></li>
                <li class="menu_list_items"><a href="#">Txt2</a></li>
                <li class="menu_list_items"><a href="#">Txt3</a></li>
                <li class="menu_list_items"><a href="#">Txt4</a></li>
                <li class="menu_list_items"><a href="#">Txt5</a>
                    <div class="drpDown">
                        <ul class="drp_dwn_ul">
                            <li><a href="#">Txt6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Txt7</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul> 
        </nav>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```